# Алгоритм удаления слова из массива

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Подадются столбиком слово(word) и слова (words) читаются они до пробела.
Надо найти в строке words слово word и удалить его.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define N 100000
char word[N], words[N];
int find(char* word, char* words) //сама функция по нахождению слова в строке
{
char* istr;
//Поиск строки
istr = strstr(words, word);
    int t = istr - words;
    
    if (istr == NULL) return -1;

    else return t;

    return 0;
}

int main() {
int wd = 0, ws = 0;
scanf("%[^' ']s", word); while (getchar() != ' '); printf("\n"); //само заполнение до пробела
scanf("%[^' ']s", words); while (getchar() != ' ');
wd = strlen(words);
ws = strlen(word);
int sym_word = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ws; i++) { // подсчет из сколькиз букв состоит слово
    if (word[i] != ' ') sym_word++;
}
//new_len_words-общая длинна words_v2(с энатром)\
WDW(weight delite word) -  длина удаляемого слово(с энтором)\
alllenn-общее число бкув+ентеров\
y-номер яцеки где начинается удаляемое слово\

int y = find(word, words);
int konec_y = 0, new_len_words;
int wdw = sym_word + 1;
konec_y = wdw + y; //номер ячейки где заканчивается удаляемое слово
int y = find(word, words);
if (y != -1) { // -1- значит потора нет и удалять ничего не надо 
    if (y != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) { //удаление слова 
        words_v2[i] = words[i];
    }
    for (int i = y; i < (alllenn-wdw) ; i++) {
        for (int s = konec_y; s <alllenn; s++) {
            words_v2[i] = words[s];
        }

    }
}
printf("\n");
new_len_words = alllenn- wdw;
for (int i = 0; i < new_len_words; i++) {
    printf("%c", words_v2[i]);
 }

return 0;
}
```

при перезаписании вместо удаляемого слова просто заполняется iiiiiiiiiii можете подсказать что не так?

Comment: Если найденное слово начинается с позиции ```j```, то начиная с этой позиции выполнить операцию ```works[k]=wprks[k+sym_word+1]``` переместив тем самым весь конец строки. Ну, или использовать для той же цели функцию копирования строки

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов я переделала код, я хотела перезаптсать в новый массив words_v2 но почему то на месте удаляемого слова ставится просто iiiiiiii можете подскать в чем дело?

Comment: Для начала несколько странностей... Зачем вложенные ```if (y != -1) {```?  И зачем вложенные циклы при копировании??

Comment: ```for (int i = y; i < (alllenn-wdw) ; i++)     words_v2[i] = words[i+wdw]; ```

Comment: Да, и зачем дважды вызов ```find```?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов  `if (y != -1)` это проверка есть ли повтор если повтор нет то функция find вернет -1Б а вложенные я просто не знала как по другому
спасибо большое , сейчас исправлю

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов а где вы видите второй вызов функции `find` ?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов спасибо большое теперь все хорошо работает
можете пожалуйста написать не в комментарии, чтобы я могла выделить ваш ответ?

Comment: Второй ```find``` находится перед ```if (y != -1 )```, первый на 4 строки выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим фрагмент Вашего кода:

```
if (y != -1) { // -1- значит потора нет и удалять ничего не надо 
    if (y != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) { //удаление слова 
        words_v2[i] = words[i];
    }
    for (int i = y; i < (alllenn-wdw) ; i++) {
        for (int s = konec_y; s <alllenn; s++) {
            words_v2[i] = words[s];
        }

    }
}
```

В нем присутствуют две ошибки:

1. Вложенный `if` Во-первых, он не нужен, во-вторых, это, видимо, просто опечатка, т.к. не сходятся фигурные скобки блоков кода.
2. Копирование второй  части строки сделано вложенным циклом, что дает неверный результат. (На досуге на листке бумаги пройдите этот код по шагам, и посмотрите, что получится). Здесь достаточно такого кода:

```
for (int i = y; i < (alllenn-wdw) ; i++)     words_v2[i] = words[i+wdw];
```

В результате исправления ошибок получится следующее:

```
if (y != -1) { // -1- значит повтора нет и удалять ничего не надо 
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) { //удаление слова 
        words_v2[i] = words[i];
    }
    for (int i = y; i < (alllenn-wdw) ; i++)     words_v2[i] = words[i+wdw];
}
```

К остальному коду, вроде бы, замечаний особых нет, кроме двух вызовов функции `find`